# How do I correctly rebind select-pane commands in tmux?

Tags: terminal, tmux

By default, tmux seems to be using

```
C-b, Left to move left a pane
C-b, Right to move right pane
...
```

I want to use

```
C-b, h to move left a pane
C-b, l to move right a pane 
...
```

Here's my current attempt in .tmux.config:

```
unbind Left
unbind Right
unbind Up
unbind Down

bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```

I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: This is what I use here and it works, tmux version 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I will answer it so that people in the future will not struggle to find the same simple answer.

The problem is that the `bind` command does not really work correctly in versions of `tmux` prior to `1.5`, and I was running `tmux` on an old system. The only correct solution, given that I lacked root, was to download the updated source and build my own version.